# Collections with photos plus their Virtual Copies

Tags: lightroom, smart-collections

How do I create a collection (or a smart collection) that contains all the photos that have virtual copies and their VCs? I want to search a folder for all the files that have VCs (either using metadata>attribute or by a smart collection) and then have the photos that have VCs and their VCs in a collection or smart collection. Selecting attribute>master photo returns all whether they have VCs or not. I tried smart collections using copy name is empty or copy name doesn't contain copy thinking I could select all, go to the folder and invert the selction -- but those didn't work either.
Thanks!

Comment: Lightroom?  Which version, in case it makes a difference in the answer

Comment: I'm using Lightroom C (just upgraded) but this is one area that hasn't changed. I don't think it matters what version for collections and virtual copies. Thanks!

Comment: I thought that http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/extended-search would work, but I do not get the results you wanted. Perhaps you should ask the author of that tool how to do what you want.